# Not able to increment count using state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

Following is my code in which I am trying to increment the count using click button but it's not updating the value. Though I am not getting any error in console as well. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**JS Code -**

```
class App1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }
    this.setCount = this.setCount.bind(this)
  }

  setCount() {
    this.setState((state) => {
      count: state.count + 1
    })
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <hr />
        <h3>test increment</h3>
        <button onClick={this.setCount}>Click</button>
      <p>{this.state.count}</p>
      </>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App1 />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaMOEp

Comment: Great stuff including all the necessary code and not a lot of extraneous code! Most people get that wrong. :-) Next time, rather than an off-site resource like codepen, please make your runnable example runnable **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ahha thx for the stack snippet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything. You could use `return` in side callback.

```
setCount() {
    this.setState((state) => {
       return {count: state.count + 1}
    }))
  }
```

Or you can use avoid using of `return` wrapping you return value in `()` after `=>`

```
setCount() {
   this.setState((state) => ({
      count: state.count + 1
   }))
}
```

Comment: This will not work. Will throw an error using setting state of undefined

Answer (score 2):

```
this.setState((state) => {
  count: state.count + 1
})
```

In the above code, the curly brackets are the body of the function, `count:` is a [line label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), and `state.count + 1` is an expression that never gets used. If you want to use the concise arrow function syntax to return an object literal, then you need to wrap the object in parentheses:

```
this.setState((state) => ({
  count: state.count + 1
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `setCount()`, where you miss a pair of parenthesis! Here's the correct version:

```
setCount() {
    this.setState((state) => ({
        count: state.count + 1
    }));
}
```

There are two parenthesis more! One right after the `=>` and one at then of the `this.setState()` call.